# Persist many to many with SelectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jpa, checkbox, many-to-many, persistence

My question is similar to [JPA persist many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266390/jpa-persist-many-to-many)

But, I have two entities: Roles and Users, with a Many to Many relation, that is represented by rolesusers table. In my application, I'm using JSF 2.0, and I have a form to manipulate User data, and a form with a list of all Roles names and a selectBooleanCheckbox to see the user's roles (checked if yes). Additionally it must have the possibility to add or remove a rol (checking or unchecking the selectBooleanCheckbox), but when I do it, I have two problems:

1: To check the role that this user has, I have in the value of the selectBooleanCheckbox this syntax:

```
<h:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="ASIGNADO"/>
 </f:facet>
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{usuariosController.selected.rolesList.contains(itemRole)}">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{true}">
   <f:ajax listener="#{rolesView.selectRoleListener(usuariosController.selected, itemRole)}" render="@form" />
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
 </h:panelGroup>
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!usuariosController.selected.rolesList.contains(itemRole)}">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{false}">
   <f:ajax listener="#{rolesView.selectRoleListener(usuariosController.selected, itemRole)}" render="@form" />
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:column>
```

But when the `selectRoleListener` is executed, it throws a `javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException /users.xhtml @224,102 value="#{true}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation`.

2: If I remove the `value="#{true}"` and replace it with `value="true"`, the checkbox is not selected when the user has the role specified in list, but it seems the selectRoleListener is executed, but the changes are not visible in data base.

Can you help me with this case? I hope you understood me.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not the right usage of checkboxes in JSF. First of all, is there a specific reason why you use a `<h:dataTable><h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` instead of just a `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`?

Comment: Not really. It's just for manipulate the Roles list (for all roles in Roles table). But I had not thought it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, it look like that you somehow missed that a [`<h:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyCheckbox.html) exists among [the standard JSF component set](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html). This overcomplicated and incorrect approach can then be simplified as follows:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.user.roles}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableRoles}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

*(converters/labels/layout, etc omitted for brevity)*

Wherein `#{bean}` has an `User user` property which in turn has a `List<Role> roles` property representing the selected roles. Then there's a `List<Role> availableRoles` property representing all available roles (which can be held in a different, applicationscoped, bean if necessary).

---

As to the `PropertyNotWritableException` which you got: that's pretty self-explaining, there's no setter for the property. In other words, the `value="#{true}"` does not represent a true model property at all. You should be referencing a model property which has a getter and a setter like so `#{bean.value}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using property `value="#{true}"` because it didn't check the selectBooleanCheckbox when the role in list was an user's role. But I'll try with selectManyCheckbox. Thank you!